# Test failed for pass list range

Tags: python, binary-search

Having trouble with a failed test -- the error is "pass list(range(10)), search for 5
Target is in index: 5
Test Failed: 5!= None"

The directions are as follows: "Write a binary search function that, instead of returning -1 when the target value is not in the list, raises a TargetNotFound exception (you'll need to define this exception class). Otherwise it should function normally. Name this function bin_except."

Below is my code -- any recommendations on how to fix this?

```
class TargetNotFound(Exception):
    pass


def bin_except(a_list, value):
    first = 0
    last = len(a_list) - 1
    found = False
    index = -1
    while first <= last and not found:
        middle = (first + last) // 2
        if a_list[middle] == value:
            found = True
            index = middle
        else:
            if value < a_list[middle]:
                last = middle - 1
            else:
                first = middle + 1
    try:
        if not found:
            raise TargetNotFound
        else:
            print("Target is in index: ", index)
    except TargetNotFound:
        print("Target is not in array ")
```

Comment: Aren’t you immediately catching the exception you throw? Is that intended?

Comment: im not sure i understand?